# На какие внешние ресурсы загружать img для уменьшения размера проекта на сервере?

Tags: javascript, html, css, изображения, оптимизация-сайтов

Есть веб-проект с большим количеством web-p и jpeg картинок. Собственно на какие внешние ресурсы можно их загрузить и ссылаться в разметке, чтобы в самом проекте оставить только стили и скрипты?